# Immutable collections in Doctrine 2?

Tags: orm, collections, doctrine, domain-driven-design, doctrine-orm

I'm looking for a way to return an immutable collection from a domain object in Doctrine 2. Let's start with this example from the [doc](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html):

```php
class User
{
    // ...

    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }
}

// ...
$user = new User();
$user->getGroups()->add($group);
```

From a [DDD](http://domaindrivendesign.org/) point of view, if `User` is the aggregate root, then we'd prefer:

```php
$user = new User();
$user->addGroup($group);
```

But still, if we do need the `getGroups()` method as well, then we ideally don't want to return the internal reference to the collection, as this might allow someone to bypass the `addGroup()` method.

Is there a built-in way of returning an immutable collection instead, other than creating a custom, immutable collection proxy? Such as...

```php
    public function getGroups()
    {
        return new ImmutableCollection($this->groups);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest (and recommended) way to do it is [toArray()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html#_toArray):

```php
return $this->groups->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the easiest way to achieve that would be to use [`iterator_to_array`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php).

`iterator_to_array` converts iterable objects into arrays, so instead of returning the collection directly, you'd just do `return iterator_to_array($this->foo);`.

This has the added bonus of making it possible to use functions like `array_map` on the returned lists, since they don't work on array-like objects.

Comment: Just noticed that `return $this->groups->toArray();` produces the same result!

Comment: You could also do `return new ArrayCollection($this->groups->toArray());` if you wanted to retain the ArrayCollection functionality