# Howto decorate doctrine collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, decorator, symfony4

I want to decorate a doctrine2 collection and working with symfony4.

So i had an entity

```
class Entry
{
    protected $title;

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

And a decorator:

```
class EntryDecorator
{
    protected $entry;

    public function __construct(Entry $entry)
    {
        $this->entry = $entry;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return '----'; // just for testing ;-)
    }
}
```

And in my Controller i load the complete entries from the database using:

```
$entries = $this->entryRepository->findAll()
```

And my view is simple as this:

```
{% for entry in entries  %}
    {{ entry.getTitle }}
{% endfor %}
```

So, now i want to decorate the whole collection.

In SF4 i found [How to Decorate Services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) which looks fine, but this doesn't work for this situation.

**Because:** doctrine returns an immutable collection (see this topic [Immutable collections in Doctrine 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375334/immutable-collections-in-doctrine-2))

So i thought something like this will be fine:

```
array_walk($entries, function($entry) {
    return new EntryDecorator($entry);
});
```

But doesn't work, because the collection is immutable.

Now i have the following which is working:

```
$entries = [];

foreach($this->entryRepository->findAll() as $entry) {
    $entries[] = new EntryDecorator($entry);
}
```

But it looks hm, ok.

So my question is:
Is there a better solution to decorate a doctrine collection?

**Update:**
currently, im using `array_map()` for this.

```
array_map(function ($entry) {
    $decorator = new EntryDecorator($entry);

    return $decorator;
}, $entries);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want "transform" the data in your twig template, if suggest you use a [TwigExtension](https://symfony.com/doc/master/templating/twig_extension.html) and create a custom filter (or function).

```
{# filter #}
{% for entry in entries  %}
    {{ entry.getTitle|my_decorator }}
{% endfor %}

{# function #}
{% for entry in entries  %}
    {{ my_decorator(entry) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but it will only work for `Twig`. If i want to use another template engine or build an json response, then this will not work. i'm searching for a solution to "inject" the decorator into doctrine e.g.